# Solr working with Django finds only exact matches

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have a django application and a search bar on the index page. I install haystack and solr.
I typed python manage.py build_solr_schema and get paste the following xml to example/solr/conf/schema.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema name="default" version="1.4">
  <types>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d"/>
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
    <fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>

  <fields>
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>


    <field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

  </fields>

  <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
</schema>
```

I have an object called titled as "foorightfoo" . When I search for "foo" nothing appears, but 
when I search for "foorightfoo" answer comes.Also when I check from solar admin panel, same situation continues...
My search is working for only exact match.Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I fixed the issue by manipulating the last section of my schema.xml like

```
- <field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

+ <field name="text" type="ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

changing the searched field type with ngram do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a wild-card `*` at the end, so query like

```
q=title:foo*
```

Comment: still the same.. http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=foorightfoo is ok but http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=foo* comes empty

Comment: The analysis tool should help you debug this for yourself then. See what tokens are produced at index time for `foorightfoo`. For the default Solr 4.0 example installation it is at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/analysis. Map it for your path and try